# sonata disallow delete if an entity is linked to another

Tags: sonata-admin, sonata

i need to disallow delete function in an entity if is linked to another

for example there are two entity Product and Category, and Category is linked to Product with a relationship oneToMany or ManytoMany

i want disallow the delete function of an element in Category if this element is linked in a product element

is possible?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the ArrayCollection contains more than 0 entities. If that is the case block deletion of the entity by using some sort of validation. Since you didn't specify wether you're submitting an admin, form or block. I will assume this is for an admin class.

There is [an chapter about validation within admin classes](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/conditional_validation.html) in the Sonata Documentation. Within the `validate(ErrorElement $errorElement, $object)` you can check `$object` for the collection and amount of entities in the colleciton.